# How would you return error codes in an embedded system?

Tags: c, error-handling, arm, embedded, i2c

So I'm programming my own HAL and now I'm in a little dispute with myself about how to return error codes from functions.
So the general idea is that I have an `I2C_read()` function:

```c
int32_t I2C_read(I2C_handle_t i2c, uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg);
```

which returns the byte on success, or a negative error value when an error occurs. Since I only read one byte here from I2C the `int32_t` will have enough space to handle both, error code on error and read byte on success.
But now I've read that it is general bad practice to return two different "types" of data from a function.
So my dispute is now how I should do this:
Either I do:

```c
i2c_err_t I2C_read(I2C_handle_t i2c, uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data);
```

where I just put in `data` as a buffer for the read byte and return the error code
or

```c
uint8_t I2C_read(I2C_handle_t i2c, uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, i2c_err_t *err);
```

where I return the data and put in a buffer for the error.

So which one would you guys say is better or maybe you can give me another idea how I could implement this.

I also thought about creating a `struct` where I put in the returned value and the error code, but I thing that would be too overengineered 'cause of the handling of arrays with this kind of approach.

Comment: C traditionally returned negative value to mark a failure while zero or positive indicated some form of success.

Comment: *"But now I've read that it is general bad practice to return two different "types" of data from a function."* I wouldn't necessarily call it *bad*, just not optimal. If you do embedded development, it may sometimes acceptable trade-off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But now I've read that it is general bad practice to return two different "types" of data from a function.

Indeed, it is often better to split data and error handling, so there's no accidental mix-ups. This also enables more advanced error handling (more error causes than one).

```
i2c_err_t I2C_read(I2C_handle_t i2c, uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data);
```

This version is how most professional APIs are designed - with the return type (enum, struct etc) reserved for the result variable. Commonly, every single public function in that library would use this same return type, but document which error codes it returns under which conditions.

Technically, it's not wrong to pass the error code through a parameter either, but using the return type is "de facto standard" and how most libraries do it.

Also, it means you can write code like: `if(I2C_read(...) == SOMETHING)`, in case the caller is only interested in checking one specific result code.

It's also common practice to have the caller pass these errors along to some project-wide error handler, which prints/logs/takes action etc.

Comment: Thats what I also thought about. Thank you so much for the quick answer and for your time :D

Comment: OP's question is about C, but I wonder if there can be an alternative approach when using C++. I assume using exceptions is not an option in an uC-level embedded system. Maybe returning two results at once using C++17 *structured binding*?

Comment: @Tagli, you could return a struct rather than an error code. Like `struct i2c_result { int32_t err; type1 res1; type2 res2; /* etc */ }`. Using other fields would be valid only if `res.err` is 0.

Comment: @tstanisl Thats what I also thought, but I think that would add a unnecessary bit of complexity. Especially when handling arrays of data.
But I mean if this is needed and nobody minds the extra complexity then it would generally be a great idea.

Comment: @moonraccoon, when returning arrays it's usually better to let the caller allocate the memory and return a number of valid entries. See how `snprintf` handles such a problem

Comment: @Tagli Far as I know, C++ still supports enums. If you have a simple solution to a problem, then don't run off looking for a more complicated solution just because you can. _This_ is perhaps the main reason why C++ can't be used in (embedded) systems: C++ programmers going haywire by using needlessly complicated language features just because they can, not because there is a problem that those features solve.

Comment: @Tagli - C++17 supports [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which works well in some conditions where you need to discriminate between returning _nothing_ and a _value of specific type_. It basically wraps a simplified version of the struct proposed by tstanisl. But using this without exceptions (i.e. all of embedded) is not really quite as butter smooth as one might imagine in practice. I've found it useful in a few corner cases.